# How to disable builds-concurrency on master in circle-ci/azure-pipeline/any-other-ci?

Tags: continuous-integration, azure-pipelines, continuous-deployment, circleci, continuous-delivery

It is considered a bug to run deployment scripts concurrenctly.

I failed to find a solution to it in circle-ci, azure-pipeline, code-fresh and more..

Bitbucket-pipelines has a very nice solution:

- only one deployment script is running against a specific enviroment
- new builds will automatically stop older (running) builds

As I want to move out of bitbucket, I can't do it until I will find any other CI that has this basic ability.

---

Maybe I'm missing something because to my knowlege, all the CIs themselves must have this problem as well when they deploy their new features. unless they use jenkins and just lock the project haha...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can achieve this with azure release pipeline.

If you are to use [Classic UI Azure release pipeline.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/define-multistage-release-process?view=azure-devops) You can achieve stopping older builds when new builds is queued by configuring **Deployment queue settings**.  See below screenshot:

1,Set the `Maximum number of parallel deployments` to control the parallel deployment.  Check **Deploy latest and cancel others** will only deploy the latest queued deployment. All the previous queued(not running yet) deployment will be cancelled. But if a previous deployment is running. The latest queued build will have to wait until the running build to be completed unless you manually cancel it.

[image]

If you want to cancel the older running builds you can add a script task to call the rest api to cancel the previous running builds. See the example in below yaml pipeline example:

2, To only deploy to one target you can configure the **Deployment targets** as below in a **[deployment group](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/deployment-groups/?view=azure-devops) job**

[image]

If you are to use Yaml pipleline. The `Deploy latest and cancel others` and `Deployment group jobs` are not supported for yaml pipeline. See this use voice [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/918698/need-deploy-latest-and-cancel-the-others-feature-i.html).

In Yaml pipeline, you can use [deploy jobs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/deployment-jobs?view=azure-devops) and [environments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/environments?view=azure-devops) instead. You can configure the [Define approvals and checks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/approvals?view=azure-devops&tabs=check-pass) for the **Environment** to enable the [Exclusive lock](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/release-notes/2020/sprint-172-update#exclusive-deployment-lock-policy) to ensure only a single run deploys to this environment at a time. And configure the [deployment strategy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/deployment-jobs?view=azure-devops#rolling-deployment-strategy) to set the maxparallel deployment.

To cancel the older running builds you can add a script task to call the [rest api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/builds/update%20build?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0). See below example: Check my answer to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59977600/azure-devops-multi-stage-pipelines-stuck-waiting-for-approvals/59989265#59989265) for more information.

```
- task: PowerShell@2
  inputs:
        targetType: inline
        script: |
          $header = @{ Authorization = "Bearer $(system.accesstoken)" }
          $buildsUrl = "$(System.TeamFoundationCollectionUri)$(System.TeamProject)/_apis/build/builds?api-version=5.1"
          echo $buildsUrl
          $builds = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $buildsUrl -Method Get -Header $header
          $buildsToStop = $builds.value.Where({ ($_.status -eq 'inProgress') -and ($_.definition.name -eq "$(Build.DefinitionName)") -and ($_.id -ne $(Build.BuildId))})
          ForEach($build in $buildsToStop)
          {
            echo $build.id
            $build.status = "cancelling"
            $body = $build | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 10
            $urlToCancel = "$(System.TeamFoundationCollectionUri)$(System.TeamProject)/_apis/build/builds/$($build.id)?api-version=5.1"
            echo $urlToCancel
            Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $urlToCancel -Method Patch -ContentType application/json -Body $body -Header $header
          }
```

Comment: thanks! i will try it. (on other topic, this is extrimly complicated and i don't understand why no ci makes it easy and gives us a working solution out of the box. this is needed in every pipeline for every programming language in every product and company)