# How to ensure proper order of execution when using the Business Hours check for Azure Devops pipelines?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I want my deployment pipelines to run only outside business hours. Say, between 10pm and 4am overnight.
I can achieve that by using the Business Hours check. By the way, I use another timezone to solve the issue with midnight (Azure Devops will complain that 4am is before 10pm). Like Cook Islands, where they are about half a day behind us.

That said, when I am developing, I often do multiple commits and merges per day. That results in more than one deployment pipeline waiting in the queue.
I don't know how to automatically cancel any waiting pipeline when a new one is triggered. But I want at least be sure that they will be executed in the right order.
When having more than one build agent, can I still be sure they will be taken from the queue first-in-first-out?

Comment: I've combined the "Business Hours" check with the "Exclusive Lock" check in order to achieve that. But I just noticed today, that in rare cases not the last run proceeds; It looks completely random then. Looks like the same issue...

Answer (score 0):

When two pipelines are running in parallel you cannot guarantee which one will end first.

If the problem is the deployment when developing you could set a condition on the deployment stage/job/step like this `eq($(Build.Reason), Manual)` or like this `eq($(Build.Reason), Schedule)`
and use a [schedule trigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/scheduled-triggers?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#scheduled-triggers) to trigger it only on a given time.

Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml

Comment: I can't use Build.Reason as a starting point in the Build Pipeline since it's always 'PullRequest'. The Deploy Pipeline is triggered by any successful Build Pipeline, regardless of Build.Reason. I wrote a task to cancel waiting deployments in the final step of the Build Pipeline. This requires using Azure DevOps API via PowerShell and setting specific permissions for the Build Service user. It is inspired by the response to a question asked a few years back: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57004926. I'm preparing a detailed article on this and will share the link here once it's complete."